# Rxjs - Observable subscribe to watching one variable, completing on a change

Tags: rxjs, observable

i am trying to create an observable to watch a variable in my app, and as soon as the variable changes to null, all subscribers should be notified and completed. I was assuming the takeUntil property would work best but I seem to be doing something wrong.

```
export default class service {
    constructor($window) {
        'ngInject'
        this._currentObject = new BehaviorSubject(null)
    }

    open(config){
        this._currentObject.next(config)
        return this._currentObject.asObservable().takeUntil(null)
    }

    close(){
        this._currentObject.next(null)
    }
}
```

so for any methods that call the open function, i want to return them a new Observable that they can subscribe to, so they know when the object changed back to null.  This would occur from somewhere else in the app that called the **close** method

```
service.open({
            prop:'test',
            prop2: 'right',
        }).subscribe(s => {
            // fires when currentObject is set back to null 
            //automatically completes
        })
```

When trying this, i get an error on takeUntil (*You provided 'null' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.* )

I'm not even sure this is a decent approach, but was wondering if someone could take a look and give me advice.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`takeUntil`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil) takes an observable as an argument - not a value - and takes until that observable emits a value.

[`takeWhile`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile) is more likely the operator you need, as it takes a predicate:

```js
const source = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(null);
source
  .takeWhile((value, index) => (value !== null) || (index === 0))
  .subscribe(
    (value) => console.log(value),
    undefined,
    () => console.log("completed; changed back to null")
  );
  
source.next(1);
source.next(2);
source.next(3);
source.next(null);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly :)  still need to learn the myriad operators in rxjs